# How can I define a class that is almost the same as List

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In Scala, suppose I would like a class that is just like List[String] except for a few methods, for example toString.

What I have now is

```
    case class FQN(val names : List[String]) extends LinearSeq[String] {

        def this( params : String* ) { this( List(params : _* )) }

        override def toString() : String = {
              names.reduce((a,b) => b++"."++a)
        }

        override def apply( i : Int ) = names.apply( i ) 

        override def length() = names.length

        override def tail = new FQN( names.tail )  

        override def head = names.head 

        override def isEmpty = names.isEmpty

        def ::( str : String) = new FQN( str :: names ) 

    }
```

However, what I would like is for `fqn0 ++ fqn1` to give me an `FQN`, just as `list0 ++ list1` gives a `List'; it currently gives a`LinearSeq[String]`.  So something is not as I would like.

Also I made `FQN` a case class in order to get equals and hashCode to be the way I want, but I'm not sure whether this is the best way to do it.

**What is the best way to make a class that is just like `List`, but implements certain methods differently?**

Comment: Probably easier to define an implicit class on List that adds your custom function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how implicit classes help.  I tried `implicit class FQN( names : List[String] ) {
     override def toString() : String = {
      names.reduce((a,b) => b++"."++a)
  }
 }` But then `fqn0 ++ fqn1` gives an error that `++` is not a member of FQN.

Comment: I'm saying you don't use FQN at all, you just write functions in your implicit class which will return either your result type (e.g., `String`) or another `List`.  Implementing your own Scala collections is likely to be painful.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell Do you want to override (redefine) existing methods or add new methods to the interface of `List`? Implicit classes are a great way to enrich an interface with new methods, but are probably not good if you want to, e.g., override the `toString` method. Is adding a second `toString`-method, e.g., `fqnToString` an option?

Comment: @Ryan I think I see what you are saying now. See my answer.

Comment: @KuluLimpa I would prefer to use toString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guts tell me that you are probably better off not implementing a specialized `FQN` collection, but hide the collection as part of the internal implementation of `FQN`, effectivly removing the corresponding operations from the interface of `FQN`. What I mean is, you should ask yourself whether the world must really see `FQN` as a `Seq` and be able use all corresponding operations, or whether it is enough to maybe add solely the operation `++` with a dispatch to the underyling list's `++` operation to `FQN`'s interface.

However, the Scala guys apparently did a great job in generalizing their collections and at second glance, implementing your own collection doesn't seem like a huge pain. The [documentation I posted in a comment](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl_8.html) explains how to reuse code when implementing your own collection and I recommend you read it.

In short, you'd want to mix-in traits with a name of the form `xxxLike`; in your specific case `LinearSeqLike[String, FQN]` and override the method `newBuilder: mutable.Builder[String, FQN]` to make methods like `drop` return a `FQN`.

The builder alone however isn't powerful enough on its own: Methods such as `map` (and to my surprise `++`) may map the elements contained in the collection to a different type that is not necessary supported by your collection. In your example, FQN("foo").map(_.length) is not a legal `FQN`, so the result cannot be a `FQN`, however `FQN("Foo").map(_.toLowercase)` is legal (at least regarding the types). This problem is solved by bringing an implicit `CanBuildFrom` value to the scope.

The final implementation could look like this:

```
final class FQN private (underlying: List[String]) extends LinearSeq[String] with LinearSeqLike[String, FQN] {
  def apply(i: Int): String = underlying.apply(i)

  def length = underlying.length

  /** From the documentation of {LinearSeqLike}:
   *  Linear sequences are defined in terms of three abstract methods, which are assumed
   *  to have efficient implementations. These are:
   *  {{{
   *     def isEmpty: Boolean
   *     def head: A
   *     def tail: Repr
   *  }}}
   */
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = underlying.isEmpty

  override def head: String = underlying.head

  override def tail: FQN = FQN.fromSeq(underlying.tail)

  override def newBuilder: mutable.Builder[String, FQN] = FQN.newBuilder

  def ::(str: String) = new FQN(str :: underlying)

  override def toString(): String = {
    underlying.mkString(".")
  }
}

object FQN {

  implicit def canBuildFrom: CanBuildFrom[FQN, String, FQN] =
    new CanBuildFrom[FQN, String, FQN] {
      def apply(): mutable.Builder[String, FQN] = newBuilder
      def apply(from: FQN): mutable.Builder[String, FQN] = newBuilder
    }

  def newBuilder: mutable.Builder[String, FQN] =
    new ArrayBuffer mapResult fromSeq

  def fromSeq(s: Seq[String]): FQN = new FQN(s.toList)

  def apply(params: String*): FQN = fromSeq(params)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments from @Ryan and @KuluLimpa (or at any rate my understanding of them), here is an approach

```
type FQN = List[String] 

implicit class FQNWithFQNToString( names : List[String] ) {
    def fqnToString() : String = {
        names.reduce((a,b) => b++"."++a)
    }
}
```

Now everything you can do with `List[String]`, you can do with `FQN`. For example `fqn1++fqn2` gives an `FQN`.  In order to get the string I want, I can use `fqn.fqnToString`.

I find this answer less than satisfactory for two reasons

- Weak type checking. There is no error if any old list of `Strings` is treated as an FQN. In particular I can't define a type `QN` (for qualified name) and have a compile time error if I use a `QN` where a `FQN` is needed.
- There are now two ways to convert an `FQN` to a string.  I have to be sure to use the right one in each case. If I create another name `QN` for `List[String]`, I'll then have three ways to convert an object to a string. This is starting to feel very non-object-oriented.

Comment: This probably feels non-object-oriented because it's rather functional programming: This implementation is very similar to adding the function `fqnToString(names: List[String])` with the slight difference that the implicit class makes the function part of the interface of `List`. This isn't necessary a bad thing, but in your specific case, I agree that having two `toString` methods around isn't ideal. The problem is, that you don't want to add new features to the interface, but change existing behavior, hence a functional way won't yield a satisfying solution.

Comment: The only satisfying solution I can think of is to follow your initial implementation and override all methods you need redefined. This is especially painful as you are dealing with the fairly complex Scala collections. Maybe [this documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl_0.html) can help? However, you should probably rethink why `FQN` needs to implement the interface in the first place! Does `FQN` need to be used polymorphically where `LinearSeq[String]` is expected? Can't you simply hide the collection as part of the implementation?

Comment: @KuluLimpa I will read the The Architecture of Scala Collections in detail.  I don't think, though, that it is a question of functional style vs. object-oriented style. In Haskell, for example, I could create a `newtype` based on `[String]` and then make my new type derive `Monad` but not `Show`.